# Basic Search Question - Searching a list and applying a filter

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a custom list of a few thousand names of people and a few columns. 
For example: FirstName, LastLast and Yes/No Column called Active.
What i am hoping to create is a custom view that by default shows no items in the columns, with a simple search box above that where someone could search for a LastName, and when they click search have the view populate with results that contain the given LastName + Only Active = Yes. I want to avoid having to teach users to use the filter option after they search.

In SharePoint 2013, are there out of the box web parts that i can add to a blank web part page or list view that can achieve this? If so, can you step me through that? Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach customized search results in SharePoint.

It sounds like you most likely need to use the Content Search Web Part.  The content Search Web Part allows you to append custom query text to a user's search phrase and to target specific scopes for your search.  Please see this [step-by-step guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-particular-sp-list-items-using-content-search-webpart-cswp-in-sharepoint-o/) to configuring this web part to search only a single list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Search Scopes are a little over my head.  I was hoping to find something a little more out of the box.  I found the link below for a Text Filter Web Part.  Almost Perfect for me except a null search exposes all items. Any tips to hide the list view if someone sends a null value in the text filter? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-Filter-Web-Part-to-a-List-View-Web-Part-4f3f6c10-0a1b-479d-8b4d-c4f1bf49bb3f#bms1